How to add a comma before a publication year?
In the following MWE, I have to insert a comma before the publication year and just after the volume and number 92(3). How to dot it?
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-verbose, articlein=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]   {title}{#1\isdot}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{Chiantaretto2005,
author = {Chiantaretto, Jean-François}, 
title = {À propos de la première transgression}, 
journal = {Topique}, 
volume = {92}, 
number = {3}, 
pages = {111--125}, 
year = {2005}, 
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text here \autocite{Chiantaretto2005}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}


Are you sure you want to combine commas with a round bracket around the year? Both combined looks odd...

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It's French typography. It's supposed to look odd. :)

@AlanMunn In this case, the combination of comma and bracket is perfect :)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz : braget yourself! :))

It should be sufficient to add:
\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}

This is explained in §5.2 of the biblatex-ext documentation.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-verbose, articlein=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]   {title}{#1\isdot}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{Chiantaretto2005,
author = {Chiantaretto, Jean-François}, 
title = {À propos de la première transgression}, 
journal = {Topique}, 
volume = {92}, 
number = {3}, 
pages = {111--125}, 
year = {2005}, 
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text here \autocite{Chiantaretto2005}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}


